# Notation for space of Lipschitz continuous functions

Tags: notation, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

The Lipschitz norm of a function over a domain $D \subseteq \mathbb R^n$ is easy to define: $$\|f\|_{\mathrm{Lip}} = \sup_{x,y \in D} \frac{|f(x) - f(y)|}{|x-y|}.$$  Is there a standard notation for the space of functions whose Lipschitz norm is finite?  i.e., $$X(D) = \{f \in C(D) : \|f\|_{\mathrm{Lip}} < \infty \}.$$  Even better, what about functions which are continuously-differentiable and whose derivative has finite Lipschitz norm?  $$X^1(D) = \{f \in C^1(D) : \|\nabla f\|_{\mathrm{Lip}} < \infty \}$$ I am using $X$ and $X^1$ here only as placeholders, and would prefer a better notation.

Comment: Your first space would, I think, usually be denoted by $Lip_1(D)$ or even just $Lip(D)$. There are several papers on "Lipschitz algebras" if you look on MathSciNet.

Comment: Aren't these just $C^{0,1}(D)$ and $C^{1,1}(D)$? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Both those notations are nice and succinct.  Thanks Yemon and Willie.

Comment: Yeah, but if you go with Yemon's notation then for goodness' sake write it as `$\operatorname{Lip}_1(D)$` or $\operatorname{Lip}(D)$.

Comment: Since the question has been satisfactorily answered in the comments, I am voting to close as no longer relevant. Not because it's a bad question, but we don't want it to get regularly bumped to the front page as an unanswered question, do we?

Comment: Both Yemon and Willie gave good answers.  If either one wants to leave their comment as an answer to the question, I'll be happy to choose it to give them some points.  Willie, since your reputation score is lower, you have first dibs.

Comment: \operatorname ftw!

Comment: For a domain $D\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ I would definitely go for Willie's suggestion as the standard ones.  The notations $\mathrm{Lip}(X)$ and $\mathrm{Lip}_k(X)$ are quite standard for the Lipschitz functions on the metric space $X$, resp., the k-Lipschitz functions on $X .$ 

Comment: If $D$ is open, $C(D)$ and $C(\bar{D})$ are different. If we follow these lines, what we call the Lipschitz space would be $C^{0,1}(\bar{D})$, and $C^{0,1}(D)$ would be something like a locally Lipschitz space. But I have never seen such distinction notationally for Lipschitz spaces.